# PHP database delete function only works on first row of database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
    <p><?php include 'header.php'; ?></p>
    <div align="justify">

        <td>Name:<input type="text" name="password" ></td> <!-- database -->
        <td>&nbsp; Rank:<select>
                <!--<option value="volvo">//Database</option>
                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                -->
                <?php
                require ("dbfunction.php");
                $con = getDbConnect();

        <td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Group by Rank</td> <!-- database -->
        <td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Include previous service terms</td>  <!-- database -->
    </div>
    <p><table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Watchkeeping</th>
            <th>Active</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr> <!-- database -->
        <tr> <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <?php
            if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

                $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
                        "FROM crewlist";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                 //echo "<div><a href=http://localhost/poshproject/crewlisting.php?crew_name={$row["crew_id"]}>";


                echo "<tr>.<th>" . $row["crew_name"] . "<br></br>" . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["crew_rank"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["start_date"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["end_date"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["watchkeeping"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["active"] . "</th>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"editcrew.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">Edit</a>";
                //echo "<td><center><button type=\"submit\" name=\"Delete\" value="' . $row['crew_id'].'"/>Delete</button></center></td>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">Delete</a>";
            }
            ?>
            <!--                
                            <td><center><button type="submit" value="Edit">Edit</button></center></td>
                    <td><center><button type="submit" value="Delete">Delete</button></center></td>-->
        </form></tr>

    </tr>
</table>
```

```
---------------------delete.php---------------------
<?php
//print_r($_GET);
include 'dbfunction.php';
$con = getDbConnect();

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
   $queryStr = "SELECT * FROM crewlist";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        $sqliQueryStr = "DELETE FROM `posh`.`crewlist` WHERE crew_id = ". $row['crew_id'] . "";
                }
      mysqli_query($con, $sqliQueryStr);
      header('Location: crewlisting.php');
      mysqli_close($con);
      //echo "user has been deleted";
   }
 ?>
```

Delete function only works on first row of database. When I delete the rows that are not the first, it deletes the first row instead. Not sure where the error is when I've tried pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are wrong on delete.php file. Put below code in your **delete.php** file.

```
---------------------delete.php---------------------
<?php
include 'dbfunction.php';
$con = getDbConnect();

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    $sqliQueryStr = "DELETE FROM `posh`.`crewlist` WHERE crew_id = " .       $_GET['id'];
    mysqli_query($con, $sqliQueryStr);
}
header('Location: crewlisting.php');
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: thanks bro, i pretty much solved it with your answer!

Comment: i have another question regarding the editing function, it shares the similar error that modified the whole table into the new changes i inputted into the field. Please check back my profile in awhile if you care! Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: @ChenJunhao Thanks, When you share your another question then mension me in your new question's comment.

Comment: @ChenJunhao but i didn't get. Where you mentioned give me link here?

Comment: I'm sorry! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713279/php-database-update-function-only-modified-the-first-row/32713374?noredirect=1#comment53269404_32713374

Answer (score 0):

Change your delete query as below

```
$sqliQueryStr = "DELETE FROM `posh`.`crewlist` WHERE crew_id = " .       $_GET['id'] . "";
```