# PHP database UPDATE function only modified the first row?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"> 
<?php
if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

    $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
            "FROM crewlist";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>.<th>" . $row["crew_name"] . "<br></br>" . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row["crew_rank"] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row["start_date"] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row["end_date"] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row["watchkeeping"] . "</th>";
    echo "<th>" . $row["active"] . "</th>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"editcrew.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">Edit</a>";

    echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">Delete</a>";
}
?>
```

**editcrew.php**

```
<table>
    <form action="handlecrewedit.php" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td>Crew Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CrewName" id ="CrewName"required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Crew Rank:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CrewRank" id="CrewRank" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" required></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="EndDate" id="EndDate" required></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Payroll No:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PayrollNo" id="PayrollNo" required></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee No:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="EmployeeNo" id="EmployeeNo" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Watching Keeping:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="WatchKeeping" id="WatchKeeping" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Active:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Active" id="Active" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" ></td>


        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

**handlecrewedit.php**

```
<?php

require 'dbfunction.php';
$con = getDbConnect();
$crew_id = $_POST["crew_id"];
$CrewName = $_POST["CrewName"];
$CrewRank = $_POST["CrewRank"];
$StartDate = $_POST["StartDate"];
$EndDate = $_POST["EndDate"];
$PayrollNo = $_POST["PayrollNo"];
$EmployeeNo = $_POST["EmployeeNo"];
$WatchKeeping = $_POST["WatchKeeping"];
$Active = $_POST["Active"];


if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

$queryStr = "SELECT crew_id " .
        "FROM crewlist"; 
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {        



if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    $sqlQueryStr = "UPDATE crewlist SET crew_name = '$CrewName', crew_rank = '$CrewRank', start_date = '$StartDate' "
            . ", end_date = '$EndDate', payroll_no = '$PayrollNo'"
            . ", employee_no = '$EmployeeNo', watchkeeping = '$WatchKeeping', active = '$Active' WHERE crew_id = " . $row['crew_id'] . "";


    }
    mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);
    header('Location: crewlisting.php');
    mysqli_close($con);
}




mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is another issue on my modifying entries. I'm not quite sure if I can simply copy and paste my delete code for my edit code, but here is some rough gauge of my table. Unlike the delete function, by selecting the edit function, it directs the user to the form page and it requires them to fill in the updated data.

Comment: @Kausha Mehta here it is! Sorry I'm pretty new here.

Comment: Its ok. I given the solution check it out.

Comment: @KaushaMehta Hi, I have a new inquiry to make regarding search function. My main page displays the records for all of the users, how do I make the search text box read what I type, for example when I type 'J', the records automatically refresh to names that start with 'J'. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's better if you create new question and link here. I explain your code whatever you tried in new question then i'm able to explain.

Comment: @KaushaMehta I kinda got one already but thanks! I'd have more queries coming :)

Comment: @KaushaMehta Hi, I've posted another question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835027/php-using-time-from-database-to-calculate-hours

Comment: @KaushaMehta Hi, I have a final query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839773/how-to-pass-multiple-checkbox-values-by-submitting-form
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace **editcrew.php** and **handlecrewedit.php** file code with below code.

**editcrew.php**

```
<table>
    <form action="handlecrewedit.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="crew_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
        <tr>
            <td>Crew Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CrewName" id ="CrewName"required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Crew Rank:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="CrewRank" id="CrewRank" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" required></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>End Date:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="EndDate" id="EndDate" required></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Payroll No:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="PayrollNo" id="PayrollNo" required></td>       
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee No:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="EmployeeNo" id="EmployeeNo" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Watching Keeping:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="WatchKeeping" id="WatchKeeping" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Active:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Active" id="Active" required></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" ></td>


        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

**handlecrewedit.php**

```
<?php
require 'dbfunction.php';
$con = getDbConnect();
$crew_id = $_POST["crew_id"];
$CrewName = $_POST["CrewName"];
$CrewRank = $_POST["CrewRank"];
$StartDate = $_POST["StartDate"];
$EndDate = $_POST["EndDate"];
$PayrollNo = $_POST["PayrollNo"];
$EmployeeNo = $_POST["EmployeeNo"];
$WatchKeeping = $_POST["WatchKeeping"];
$Active = $_POST["Active"];

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    $sqlQueryStr = "UPDATE crewlist SET crew_name = '$CrewName', crew_rank = '$CrewRank', start_date = '$StartDate' "
            . ", end_date = '$EndDate', payroll_no = '$PayrollNo'"
            . ", employee_no = '$EmployeeNo', watchkeeping = '$WatchKeeping', active = '$Active' WHERE crew_id = " . $crew_id . "";
    mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);
}
header('Location: crewlisting.php');
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks again! I'd try them later and let you know again!

Comment: @ChenJunhao Ok, fine let me know once you add that.

Comment: Hi @Kausha Mehta, I've tried but your code but it doesn't work. When i incorporate the code below with yours it updates the whole table.

Comment: Just to clarify, it requires " $queryStr = SELECT crew_id FROM crewlist " to work.

Comment: @ChenJunhao No it not required, because in **editcrew.php** i use "crew_id" field in hidden so i get that filed like $_POST in **handlecrewedit.php**.

Comment: Ok, I've edited them and i used print_r($_POST) to check and it prints out the array edit function followed by 'Undefined variable: row'

Comment: @ChenJunhao You have to use `$crew_id` in place of $row['crew_id']. Sorry for that. I updated my answer too.

Comment: no I'm sorry for copying blindly and went on the wrong track, it works now! I hope I can still query you more on my current project!

Comment: @ChenJunhao Its ok. I'm happy for help you more. You can upvote too :P

Answer (score 1):

Errors

1. Missing closing tag (`?>`) on here `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?" method="post">`
2. `$queryStr = "SELECT * " ."FROM crewlist";` should be `$queryStr = "SELECT * FROM crewlist"`
3. **No closing** tag comes for `<br>` on here  `echo "<tr>.<th>" . $row["crew_name"] . "<br></br>" . "</th>";`
4. You don't know how many data passing for this `$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);`, because there is no **row count validation**
5. There is no use of check this inside `while` loop. `if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con))`
6. If you are just updating the fields then you've placed the update query in the **wrong place**

Comment: Sorry I missed it out while transferring here, I'd edit it.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain more on the fourth error, since I'm relatively new.

Answer (score 0):

I think the suggested answers miss a small point.
It only updates the first row because you exit the while loop with the redirection header.

```
header('Location: crewlisting.php');
mysqli_close($con);
```

Place those two lines outside your while loop, and it should update each row.

Your while loop will than be:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {        
    // not needed. if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    $sqlQueryStr = "UPDATE crewlist SET crew_name = '$CrewName', crew_rank = '$CrewRank', start_date = '$StartDate' "
            . ", end_date = '$EndDate', payroll_no = '$PayrollNo'"
            . ", employee_no = '$EmployeeNo', watchkeeping = '$WatchKeeping', active = '$Active' WHERE crew_id = " . $row['crew_id'] . "";


    //} closing bracket of if, but the if is not needed.
    mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);

}
//after updating all rows, redirect
header('Location: crewlisting.php');
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining these minor details to me! It helps! I'd check them out later.

Comment: I've added if 

   ---- (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

    $queryStr = "SELECT crew_id " .
        "FROM crewlist"; 
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr); --

above your code and it works but it updates the whole table.
Otherwise it doesn't work.