# PHP using TIME from database to calculate hours

Tags: php, database, time

```
<?php
require 'dbfunction.php';
$con = getDbConnect();

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

                $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
                        "FROM crewlist WHERE crew_name = 'Peter'";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                $a = new DateTime($row["start_hour"]);
                $b = new DateTime($row["end_hour"]);
                $shift1 = $a->diff($b);

                $c = new DateTime($row["start_hour2"]);
                $d = new DateTime($row["end_hour2"]);
                $shift2 = $c->diff($d);

                if ($shift1 > 60*60*14) {
                    echo 'no';
                }
  ?>
```

I am trying to deduce the difference between my shift timings, with the condition of (for e.g. shift 1 not exceeding 14 hours). Thanks in advance. The fields of my form is using time as the type.

Comment: look into the [MySQL Date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) you should be able to perform all your date calculations in the query.

Comment: the only confusion I'm facing currently is using the date() function will only grant the current time depending on the format, I'm looking for printing specific number of hours to perform my if(shift > 14h).

Comment: try something like this: `$a = strtotime("2006-04-13 12:30:00");
                $b = strtotime("2006-04-12 12:30:00");
                $shift1 = $a-$b;
                $shift1=$shift1/3600;
                if ($shift1 > 14) {
                    echo 'no';
                }`

Comment: or change this part: $shift=$shift1->h if ( $shift > 14) {
                    echo 'no';
                }

Comment: @SuchitKumar I understood your code. However, how do you implement the database variable when strtotime($row["start_hour"]) can't be executed?

Comment: and why is it so.....

Comment: if your data format is 25/05/2010 you can do this.` $date = '25/05/2010';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your **start date** and **end date** into timestamp and then take difference of both.

```
$diff = abs($start-$end)
if($diff > 60 * 60 *14 ){
 // Your desired statement
}
```

if that difference exceeds to 60*60*14 then it will exceed to 14 hour.

Comment: Ok! I kinda got it after some confusion earlier, thank you and @SuchitKumar