# How to pass multiple checkbox values by submitting form?

Tags: php, database

```
    <p><?php include 'header.php'; ?></p>
    <div align="justify">


        <td><form method="post" action="search.php">
                Name:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="search" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </form></td>


        <td><form method="post" action="grouprank.php">
                Rank:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="groupby" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Group by">
            </form></td>

        <?php
        require ("dbfunction.php");
        $con = getDbConnect();
        ?>






    //start here
<form name="form" id="form" action="multiedit.php" method="post">

    <div id="show">        
    </div>
    <p><table>
        <tr>
            <th>Tick</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Watchkeeping</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr> <!-- database -->
        <tr>
            <?php
            if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

                $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
                        "FROM crewlist";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if (date("Y-m-d") > $row['start_date'] && date("Y-m-d") < $row['end_date']) {

                    echo "<tr><th>" . "<input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox2[]' value='" . $row['crew_id']. "' >" . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . "<a href=\"viewcrew.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">" . $row["crew_name"] . "</a>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["crew_rank"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["start_date"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["end_date"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["watchkeeping"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["active"] . "</th>";
                } else {

                }
            }
            ?>

        </tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

multiedit.php

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<div id="container4"><?php


require ("dbfunction.php");
$con = getDbConnect();

$checkbox2 = $_POST['checkbox2'];

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
$str =implode($checkbox2);

$queryStr = "SELECT * " .
        "FROM crewlist WHERE  ($str)";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
//if (!$check1_res) {
//    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
//    exit();
//}
print_r($_POST);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if (date("Y-m-d") > $row['start_date'] && date("Y-m-d") < $row['end_date'])     {

    echo "<tr><th>" . $row["crew_name"] . ":</th><br>";
    echo "                    <tr>
                    <td>Shift 1:</td>
                    <td><input type=\"time\" name=\"start_hour\" value=\"start_hour\" id=\"start_hour\" step=\"1800\" required> to <input type=\"time\" name=\"end_hour\" value=\"end_hour\" id=\"end_hour\" step=\"1800\" required>
                    </td>       
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shift 2:</td>
                    <td><input type=\"time\" name=\"start_hour2\" value=\"start_hour2\" id=\"start_hour2\" step=\"1800\" required> to <input type=\"time\" name=\"end_hour2\" value=\"end_hour2\" id=\"end_hour2\" step=\"1800\" required>
                    </td>       
                </tr><br><br>";
}
} 
?>
```

This is how the flow should work, I check several records, the checkbox should pass the id of the user to the edit page where it should display the records that are checked. Using print_r($_POST) there shows the id being passed into the array like so (Array ( [checkbox2] => Array ( [0] => 378 [1] => 379 ) ) ) . However it displayed out every record of the users.

Update as of 3:58 PM 30/09/2015 SGT it is solved. Misconceptions here and there.

Comment: _"Without the id in the link"_ What link?

Comment: Normally if you want to submit a form, it should be linked to the ID of the user. for example, multiedit.php?id=363

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, your form is submitting via `$_POST` not `$_GET`,  and as I can see your checkboxes contains a static text value, not a ID

Comment: Yes that's the direction I'm intending to head, but I can't seem to get the correct codes for that.

Comment: .... What? You are all ready assigning dynamic values elsewhere, I really don't understand your question.

Comment: If you add `print_r($_POST);` to your php code you'll see the array php is receiving from the browser, so you can see what your options are.

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen I've used it and discover that only the checkbox is passed, without the id.

Comment: @ChenJunhao That's because only `<input>` data is sent through a form... And you aren't assigning the `crew_id` to the checkbox either

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you find a tutorial on how php and forms works as you seem to lack fundamental understanding of this.

Comment: @OrryVandermeulen Can you enlighten me on the input statement, on whether which one to change. Thanks.

Comment: Ok well I'm new to php and I have a deadline to meet so I hope you guys would not question my ability to be able to perform as well as you guys. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For pass multiple checkbox value use input name as array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
```

Comment: Ok, there is an error if i use 

    if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

            $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
                "FROM crewlist WHERE crew_id =" . $checkbox2 . "";

Comment: Array to string conversion (notice)

Comment: For this first implode you array in comma separated values by the use of  "$str =implode($checkbox2);"  function. And then in select query use "WHERE IN ($str)"

Comment: I guessed that works for the Array to string conversion error. I have a last common error left, mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given. Up till today I still don't understand this error.

Answer (score 0):

Only the name and value is send, so one option is calling the name in your PHP.
Another option would be to look into Jquery.

Another thing, you should put the input inside your form and wrap your text in a span:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="multiedit.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id='checkbox1' name="checkbox1" onclick="load();" value="Bike">
    <span>Include previous service terms</span>
</form>
```

So now when you add `print_r($_POST);` to your php you'll see how to call it.